# Dynamically Assigning Values to a Child Class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, inheritance, polymorphism

How can I dynamically load a Child Class in C# based upon values from its inherited class?

I have a class that inherits an entity, and since I cannot cast a parent class to its child type I want to dynamically load the entity data without explicitly defining each property.

I tried doing it by looping using a foreach loop, but as you know you cannot assign values to foreach variables.

My Failed Attempt:

```
public class ABroker : DP_ePAFBroker
{
    public ABroker() : base()
    {
    }
    public ABroker(DP_ePAFBroker data)
    {
        var props = typeof(DP_ePAFBroker).GetProperties();
        foreach(object obj in this)
        {
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                obj = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
        }

    }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()//List of Objects
    {
        var props = typeof(DP_ePAFBroker).GetProperties().Select(p).ToList<Object>();
        return props.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: "since I cannot cast a parent class to its child type" -- sure you can.

Comment: @KirkWoll: If you have `class A {} class B : A {}` then you can do `A a = new B(); B b = (B)a;` but you can't do `A a = new A(); B b = (B)a;` (which is what I assume the OP means here).

Comment: Can you give us more information?  What kind of data are you trying to dynamically load here?  I'm not seeing the full picture.

Comment: @dtb you are understanding my meaning correctly.

Comment: @JoshuaEvensen my failed attempt "ABroker broker = new DP_SystemsEntities().DP_ePAFBroker.Where(b => b.SID == 3).First() as ABroker;"

Comment: @dtb Can you please post it as an answer.

Comment: are you trying to imitate a cast? you could just define an explicit conversion  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to copy all the values from an instance of your base class onto your inheritor.

You could do something like this:

```
public ABroker(DP_ePAFBroker data)
{
    foreach(var property in typeof(DP_ePAFBroker).GetProperties())
    {
        // get the value
        var value = property.GetValue(data, null);
        // set it on this instance
        property.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
}
```

Be careful copying reference types this way, though.  You can end up doing some ugly stuff and creating some really irritating bugs for yourself later on.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks!